# Posting multiple custom post type, strip_tags() error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my first question here.

I've been trying to publish posts from Wordpress front-end, so I created two custom post types 'order' and 'product'. When the user creates a Order Number (first custom post type) they can create multiple products (second custom post type) related to it.

I created a shortcode where I can put this form in pages.

Everything is working, I can publish the posts and every meta post works. The thing is, wordpress keep showing this message:

Warning: `strip_tags()` expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in **/THE-FILE-PATH AND LINE**.

I've transformed everything I could on string, but the warning keeps going, and also the code is working fine.

Here goes the code:

```
<?php 
//================================
/*--- CRIAR NOVO NO FRONT END --*/
//================================

add_shortcode('create_order_number', 'create_order_number_shortcode');
function create_order_number_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($current_user->ID!=0){ ?>
        <form method="post" id="create_order_number" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="50%">   
                        <label for="order_number">Número de Ordem:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="order_number" value="" /><br />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="50%">   
                        <label for="order_status">Status:</label>
                        <select name="order_status">
                            <option value="faturado">Faturado</options>
                            <option value="pedido">Pedido</option>
                            <option value="concluido">Concluído</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="products_unit" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="25%">   
                        <label for="product_unit">Produto</label>
                        <input type="text" name="product_unit[]" value="" /><br />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="25%">   
                        <label for="product_qtd">Quantidade</label>
                        <input type="text" name="product_qtd[]" value="" /><br />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="25%">   
                        <label for="product_status">Status:</label>
                        <select name="product_status[]">
                            <option value="faturado">Faturado</options>
                            <option value="pedido">Pedido</option>
                            <option value="concluido">Concluído</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" width="25%"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class="add_product_unit">Adicionar Produto</button>
            <button type="submit">Criar</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_order_number" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            jQuery('.add_product_unit').click(function(){
                jQuery('.products_unit').append('<tr> <td valign="top" width="25%"> <label for="product_unit">Produto</label> <input type="text" name="product_unit[]" value="" /><br /> </td> <td valign="top" width="25%"> <label for="product_qtd">Quantidade</label> <input type="text" name="product_qtd[]" value="" /><br /> </td> <td valign="top" width="25%"> <label for="product_status">Status:</label> <select name="product_status[]"> <option value="faturado">Faturado</options> <option value="pedido">Pedido</option> <option value="concluido">Concluído</option> </select> </td> <td valign="middle" width="25%"> <a href="#" class="close-'+i+'">Deletar</a> </td> </tr>');
                jQuery('.close-'+i).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
                i++;
            });
        </script>
    <?php }//endif

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_action('init','save_order_number');
function save_order_number(){
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "create_order_number") {
        /* ==== NUMBER ORDER ==== */
        $new_order = array(
            'post_title'    => $_POST['order_number'],
            'post_status'   => 'publish',          
            'post_type'     => 'order' 
        );

        $orderId = wp_insert_post($new_order);

        update_post_meta($orderId, 'order_number', $_POST['order_number']);
        update_post_meta($orderId, 'order_status', $_POST['order_status']);

        /* ==== PRODUCT UNIT ==== */
        $product_unit = $_POST['product_unit'];
        $product_qtd = $_POST['product_qtd'];
        $product_status = $_POST['product_status'];
        foreach ($product_unit as $key => $value) {
            //echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
            $this_unit = strip_tags($product_unit[$key]);
            $this_qtd = strip_tags($product_qtd[$key]);
            $this_status = strip_tags($product_status[$key]);
            $new_product = array(
                'post_title'    => $this_unit,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'product'
            );

            $productId = wp_insert_post($new_product);

            update_post_meta($productId, 'product_unit', $this_unit);
            update_post_meta($productId, 'product_qtd', $this_qtd);
            update_post_meta($productId, 'product_status', $this_status);
            update_post_meta($productId, 'product_order', $orderId);
        }

        /* ==== REDIRECT ==== */
        $the_post_url = get_post_permalink($orderId);
        //echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$the_post_url.'"</script>';
    }
}
```

The error is here:

```
'post_title'    => $this_unit,
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_type'     => 'product'
```

If I change 'product' to 'order' or 'post' the warning is not displayed.

Comment: $product_unit, $product_qtd and $product_status are always arrays?

Comment: yes they are arrays from <input type="text" name="product_unit[]" value="" />, <input type="text" name="product_qtd[]" value="" /> and <select name="product_status[]">

Comment: Shouldn't they have an index? Say, product_unit[0]

Comment: No need, values are pushed numerically and gradually.

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($_POST); die;`?

Comment: Array ( [order_number] => order_number value [order_status] => faturado [product_unit] => Array ( [0] => product_unit 1 value [1] => product_unit 2 value ) [product_qtd] => Array ( [0] => product_qtd 1 value [1] => product_qtd 2 value ) [product_status] => Array ( [0] => faturado [1] => faturado ) [action] => create_order_number )

Comment: In the warning message what's specifically **THE-FILE-PATH AND LINE**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime I understood everything. There is a metabox on my back-end wordpress 'product' custom post type dealing with the same post meta tags.

The thing is, when you call the function wp_insert_post() you enter your wordpress hook add_action( 'save_post' ), where the same input's name were being saved. So I simply added a hidden input  to filter the 'save_post' (if(get_post_type($argument->ID)=='order' && $_POST['situation'] == 'editing'){}).

Here it goes:

```
<?php

//========================
/*--- NOVO CAMPO TYPE --*/
//========================

//CRIA O TIPO DO POST NO MENU ADMIN
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_order' );
function create_post_type_order() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Nº de Ordem',
        'singular_name' => 'Nº de Ordem',
        'add_new' => 'Adicionar Ordem',
        'add_new_item' => 'Criar Número de Ordem',
        'edit_item' => 'Editar Nº de Ordem',
        'new_item' => 'Novo Número de Ordem',
        'all_items' => 'Todas Ordens',
        'view_item' => 'Ver Nº de Ordem',
        'search_items' => 'Buscar Nº de Ordem',
        'not_found' =>  'Nenhum Nº de Ordem Encontrado',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nenhum Nº de Ordem na Lixeira',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Nº de Ordem'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'order',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title')
      );
    register_post_type( 'order', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

//CRIA O METABOX LINK DENTRO DO CUSTOM POST
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'order_add_meta_box' );

function order_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'order_number_metabox',
        'Número de Ordem',
        'order_inner_meta_box',
        'order'
    );
}

function order_inner_meta_box( $argument ) {
?>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="50%">   
            <label for="order_number">Número de Ordem:</label>
            <input type="text" name="order_number" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $argument->ID, 'order_number', true ); ?>" /><br />
        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="50%">   
            <label for="order_status">Status:</label>
            <?php $order_status =  get_post_meta( $argument->ID, 'order_status', true ); ?>
            <select name="order_status">
                <option value="faturado" <?php if($order_status=='faturado'){echo ' selected';} ?>>Faturado</options>
                <option value="pedido" <?php if($order_status=='pedido'){echo ' selected';} ?>>Pedido</option>
                <option value="concluido" <?php if($order_status=='concluido'){echo ' selected';} ?>>Concluído</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="situation" value="editing">

<?php
}

//SALVA OS NOVOS METABOX NO POST
add_action( 'save_post', 'order_save_post', 10, 2 );

function order_save_post( $argument_id, $argument ) {
    //Verifica se o custom post type é o correto, garantindo-nos que estamos a guardar valores da página.
    if(get_post_type($argument->ID)=='order' && $_POST['situation'] == 'editing'){
        update_post_meta( $argument_id, 'order_number', strip_tags( $_POST['order_number'] ) );
        update_post_meta( $argument_id, 'order_status', strip_tags( $_POST['order_status'] ) );
        return true;
    } else {
        return;
    } 
}

?>
```